# Generating yesterday's date for a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

RoR newbie here. My app is routing any requests for `/year/month/day` to a controller which parses the date into an `@date` variable:

routes.rb:

```
match "/:year/:month/:day", to: 'posts#index', via: 'get', :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ }, :as => 'post_date'
```

controller:

```
if(params.has_key?(:year) && params.has_key?(:month) && params.has_key?(:day))
  @date = params[:year] + "-" + params[:month] + "-" + params[:day]
else
  @date = Date.today
end
```

What I can't figure out how to use a `<%= link_to %>` tag that could link to yesterday & tomorrow's dates. For example, if I'm visiting `http://example.com/2013/08/27`, I'd like to have a link in my view to yesterday: `http://example.com/2013/08/26` and tomorrow: `http://example.com/2013/08/28`

I've tried several inelegant solutions that all broke at some point. What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

**Solution**

It's exceptionally inelegant, but here's the final solution that worked:

controller:

```
def index
    if(params.has_key?(:year) && params.has_key?(:month) && params.has_key?(:day))
        @date = Date.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i)
    else
        @date = Date.today
    end

    # Generate variables for yesterday
    @y_year = @date.yesterday.strftime("%Y")
    @y_month = @date.yesterday.strftime("%m")
    @y_day = @date.yesterday.strftime("%d")

    @formatted_date = @date.to_time.strftime("%B %e, %Y")
    @featured = Post.where(feature_date: @date).to_a
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "Yesterday", post_date_path({ year: @y_year, month: @y_month, day: @y_day}) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP wants a day before the specific date passed on the URL,

Controller

```
if(params.has_key?(:year) && params.has_key?(:month) && params.has_key?(:day))
  @date = Date.new(params[:year],params[:month],params[:day])
else
  @date = Date.today
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to "Yesterday",'/#{@date.yesterday.year}/#{@date.yesterday.month}/#{@date.yesterday.day}' %>
```

Comment: I was commenting on your answer.. shall i remove it?

Comment: I think I'm getting lost in Rails automagic. I'm getting an error `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index", :year=>2013, :month=>8, :day=>26} missing required keys: [:month]`

Comment: I think I found my problem - @date.yesterday.month returns a single digit date (8 vs 08).

Comment: Not quite - that returns a link `http://localhost:3000/@date.yesterday.year/@date.yesterday.month/@date.yesterday.day`

Comment: Looks like I've still got the problem that the .day and .month methods return single digits. I can probably use the original solution if there is a way to convert to 2 digit day and month.

Comment: Use strftime and convert the date to 2 digits

Comment: Thanks, beck. It's not elegant at all, but it works. I put my final solution in the original question if you want to take a look.

Comment: I will give an elegant solution, tomorrow, right now, I'm off

Answer (score 0):

You can do, once you've set your reference date:

```
#for yesterday
post_date_path({ year: @date.yesterday.year, month: @date.yesterday.month, day: @date.yesterday.day})

#for tomorrow
post_date_path({ year: @date.tomorrow.year, month: @date.tomorrow.month, day: @date.tomorrow.day})
```

In your controller, I guess you'd rather have:

```
@date = Date.new(params[:year], params[:month], params[:day] )
```

But use a helper to abstract and refactor this, would be cleaner.

Comment: Wow, we got it almost the same, I saw you weren't bothering the reference date, but you edited.. Cool. I love your gmap4rails. And in fact, the OP is going to like my answer, because, his struggling point in the link_to part..